# Moving code from bitbucket repository to server

Tags: git, bitbucket

Its first time i am using Bitbucket, I have setup code on my local and after creating a repository I have synced my local code to Bitbucket repository. And everytime when I am doing commit then its working fine. Local files are getting updated on Bitbucket respository.

**The issue I am facing is:** I have a development server and I have SSH details of that. How I can move my Bitbucket code to my dev server. What will be process?

So if anyone can help me and can share step by step process then it would be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your server has **git** , if not install by
    :

```
`sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get install git`
```

on checking git on server type :

```
git or git --help
```

1. Copy **http** of the project in bit bucket.
2. go to server directory where you put the project files:

   `git clone http://saved project http here`
3. Enter the password *******
4. use git checkout dev or pull it

The files will be appear on the server.

Answer (score 0):

[Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) can handle the deployment for you.